# Data in dropdown changed when item selected in another

Tags: stimulsoft

So i have the following form:

[image]

The manager team drop down works fine, but what i want is for the manager drop down to only show managers that are in the selected manager team, what i have in the SelectedIndexChanged event for the manager team drop down is:

```
GroupName2 = cbAmGroup.SelectedItem as String;
```

From what i can see the sql query to list the managers is not refreshed after the GroupName2 parameter is filled so it always shows no managers in the drop down since the parameter is empty at when it is run. This is the SQL query that gets the manager names for the drop downs:

```
SELECT AMName, a.AMID
    FROM AM a 
INNER JOIN AMGroupMember aMem ON a.AMID = aMem.AMID
INNER JOIN AMGroup AG ON aMem.AMGroupID = AG.AMGroupID
WHERE AMGroupName = @GroupName2
```

Answer (score 0):

use *GroupName2 = cbAmGroup.text;*

Comment: The error of compilation is found in the 'SelectedIndexChanged' event of the 'cbAmGroup' component:
'Stimulsoft.Report.Dialogs.StiLookUpBoxControl' does not contain a definition for 'text' and no extension method 'text' accepting a first argument of type 'Stimulsoft.Report.Dialogs.StiLookUpBoxControl' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The sql query works fine, i have tested it many times, and again, just now.